# Why doesn't the method of images work for this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, conductors, method-of-images

> Two infinite conducting plates 1 and 2 are separated by a distance $l$. A point charge $q$ is located between the plates at a distance $x$ from plate 1. Find the charges induced on each plate.

I have a particular doubt in this question about why we can't use the method of images. My teacher told me to assume the point charge as an infinite charged plate but I didn't understand why. Would someone help me in clarifying the misconception (if any)? By using the method of images I couldn't get the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that this problem is solvable by using image charges. However, you have to make sure that you incorporate the images charge(s) of plate 1 into the calculation for the image charge(s) of plate 2. Hence, one obtains an infinite series of image charges. I'd like you to do the calculation and post your answer here.

Comment: I understood the method but I was unable to compute the complicated sum. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are willing to share your findings. This side is about concepts. So even if the series is not solved, the concept of the idea would become clearer. Please think about adding the "partial solution" to your question -- or write an answer.

Comment: I've given the solution that I came up with